# How to make an hybrid app with turbolinks-ios

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swift, turbolinks-ios

I'm new to swift and I'm confused about how to use Turbolinks-ios.
Following the TurbolinksDemo (https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-ios/tree/master/TurbolinksDemo), I can view my rails project and sign in with devise.

I'm confused about the third and fourth point :

1. User see the homepage
2. User signs in
3. After signed in, user loads another Controller with a "signed-in" tab-bar
4. User can navigate using the tab bar to load other Controllers

My code is for now pretty the same as the TurbolinksDemo, I think I need to create other Controllers with a tab-bar, but I'm not sure how to do it and how to call it.

Any examples in the room ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I came across your question looking for the same thing a week ago. This answer doesn't answer your question. But rather offer an alternative https://github.com/lazaronixon/react-native-turbolinks.

I've had success with using this lib which wraps Turbolinks ios and android libs. More importantly, if you're a web dev and not wanting to learn native languages like `swift`, this lib is definitely a good choice.